# Command line completion to enter into a folder in Vim

Tags: vim, autocomplete

When I do `:edit C:\` and keep tabbing, vim will cycle through all the files and folders. When I want to enter a folder, I think I　can do Ctrl-E. But just by chance, I typed another backslash after the folder I want to enter, e.g, `:edit C:\Documents\\`. This also seems to work. Now if I hit tabs, vim start cycling through files/folders inside C:\Documents.

I wonder what is the reason behind this. Could Anyone point me to the reference manual where this behaviour is fully explained? And does there exist even better way to stop completion in the current directory and start command line completion inside another directory?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the Ctrl-E trick, I had been looking for that for a while!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not documented, however, when you modify the text (for example, insert a backslash) during completion, vim will only auto-complete the **rest** of the string. This is because it starts a new completion cycle taking the current entry as the base.

Answer (score 1):

I use this mapping, analog to concluding insert-mode completion:

```
" c_CTRL-Y      Yes: Stop wildmode completion. Useful when completing
"           directory names and wanting to use the currently
"           completed directory and now complete its contents,
"           instead of continuing to iterate the directory names.
cnoremap <C-Y> <Space><BS>
```

But Ctrl-E works as well when you're at the end of the command-line.